# In state-space control systems, what is the correct convention for the symbol for the unit step function?

Tags: state-space

I don't wanna use the conventional "\$u(t)\$" because that is the input signal to a system represented in the state-space model.

And I don't wanna use "\$H(t)\$" (for "Heaviside") because \$H(s)\$ is the Laplace Transform of the impulse response \$h(t)\$.

What symbol do control systems engineers use for the unit step function?  I am having trouble finding an authoritative source online.  And I can't find my 45 year old textbook that might have it.

Comment: I had the same issue many years ago. I decided to use \$u_{s}(t)\$. I generally avoid using \$s\$ as a subscript when working in the Laplace domain. This is the only exception. For all the standard causal signals I use a subscripted \$u\$.

Comment: Thanks @RussellH , I think, if I get into a state-space discussion, i'm gonna use \$\theta(t)\$ as concerned said below.  but outside of state-space \$x(t)\$ is ***input*** and i wish the state-space folks had used a different letter for the state rather than \$\mathbf{x}(t)\$.  I dunno what letter it should be but they should have left "\$x(t)\$" for the input.  But the usage is too entrenched and can't be changed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that I know of is \$\theta(t)\$ for Heaviside, and \$\delta(t)\$ for Dirac. I won't declare these as absolute truths but, I will say that I have met them in several respected places (MIT papers comes to mind, no reference, though) so I'm inclined to believe it's true.

[edit] [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) seems to also use it, and they're quoting [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html).

Comment: Thanks.  \$\theta(t)\$ makes sense insofar that it's not \$u(t)\$ nor \$H(t)\$.  Of course I have always used \$\delta(t)\$ for the Dirac impulse function.